# Removing one space that was created in R

Tags: r

I have looked around for help on how to remove spaces.  I have seen help on removing all, but I just need to get rid of one.

I have columns that have names of towns in them.  I am supposed to turn them into Town, Maine.  The code I use makes it Town , Maine.  I need the space gone after the town name.

Here is the code I used,

```
hw1$citystate <- paste(hw1$Place, ", Maine")
```

Can someone either help me with the code, or show me how to get that space out from after the town name?

Answer (score 2):

The default separator to `paste` is `" "`.  Set the separator to `""` with one of these two methods:

```
hw1$citystate <- paste(hw1$Place, ", Maine", sep="")
```

or

```
hw1$citystate <- paste0(hw1$Place, ", Maine")
```